# eigenvalues and $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix} s+1 & 1-t \\ -1-t & s-1 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $s$ and  $t$ are real numbers.

(a) For which values of $s,t$， $A$ is not diagonalizable.

(b) For which choice of $s,t$ does $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}A^k$ exists

It is to see that $s+t$ and $s-t$ are eigenvalues for $A$. So $t=0$, $A$ is non-diagonalizable. There are only one eigen vector corresponding 2 repeated eigenvalue 0. For b), is it suffice to say if $|s\pm t|<1$, then the limit exists.

Comment: It isn't sufficient, because (b) is asking for a precise description of the values of $s,t$ that satisfy the property.  You need also to consider the edge cases where $|s+t| = 1$ or $|s-t| = 1$.

Comment: How would you find the precise description though? Any hints? All I know  is that we have to require the eigenvalue with modulus less (or equal) to 1. When they are equal to 1, $A^k$ could be constant

Comment: If $A^k$ is constant, it definitely has a limit as $k \to \infty$

Comment: @nerd To get a precise description, you first need to examine what happens in the cases I described (particularly $s+t = 1$ and $s-t = 1$).  $A^k$ might be constant but it also might not be.  You need to think about exactly when $A^k$ has a limit (this is pretty easy in the diagonalizable case, and the non-diagonalizable case can be studied individually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly determined that $A$ *is* diagonalizable when $t \neq 0$. However, you have yet to show that $A$ *fails* to be diagonalizable when $t = 0$.  In particular, we get the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{s+1 & 1\\
-1 & s-1} = 
sI + \pmatrix{1&1\\-1&-1}
$$
You need to somehow argue that this matrix is *not* diagonalizable for any $s$.  It suffices to show that $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is not diagonalizable.

Similarly, you've shown that $\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = 0$ when each of $|s \pm t|$ is less than $1$.  However, you need to separately handle the cases in which we have $|s + t| = 1$ or $|s - t| = 1$.

In these "edge cases", we'll find that the limit exists if $t \neq 0$, but the limit fails to exist if $t = 0$.

Comment: I think an easier approach to showing that $A$ is not diagonalizable for $t=0$ is to show that if a matrix has all identical eigenvalues, then it is diagonalizable if and only if it is diagonal. This isn't hard to see algebraically (a multiple of the identity commutes with anything).

Comment: @Ian that's probably what I'd do, but I was afraid it would seem a little too ad hoc

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciated